# Is there a shorthand for getting the value evaluated in a ternary operator?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

When using the ternary operator in C#, sometimes the expression producing the value to be evaluated can be quite long. Is there a way to get its value in one of the result expressions?

For example, if I have the ternary expression:

```
bool? foo = model.People.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Age > 21 && x.Name.StartsWith("Jo")) == null ? null : model.People.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Age > 21 && x.Name.StartsWith("Jo")).IsEnabled == "true";
```

Is there a way not to have to repeat the expression getting the item from the list in the second result expression? The only way I can think of to do this is to add an extra line:

```
var item = model.People.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Age > 21 && x.Name.StartsWith("Jo"));
bool? foo = item == null ? null : item.IsEnabled == "true";
```

I've read the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) and can't see any suggestion as to how this could be done. I'm thinking it isn't currently possible, which is a shame!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ? operator as below in C# 8 and later.

```
bool? foo = model.People.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Age > 21 && x.Name.StartsWith("Jo"))?.IsEnabled.Equals("true");
```

Or you can keep the two line form, which I find a bit clearer:

```
var item = model.People.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Age > 21 && x.Name.StartsWith("Jo"));
var foo = item?.IsEnabled.Equals("true"); // foo is a bool?
```

Comment: In your second code snippet, `foo` will not be a `string?` instead? `IsEnabled` seems to be a string (hence the need to test `== "true"`)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks, I changed it. I didn't notice the quotes. Updated the answer.

Comment: This succeeds in solving the specific problem posed in my question, but it doesn't actually use the value of the evaluated expression in the [consequent or alternative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) expressions, which is what I was hoping was possible. I was hoping there was a permissible pattern along the lines of `var foo? == model.People.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Age > 21 && x.Name.StartsWith("Jo")) == null ? null : this.IsEnabled == true`. Sometimes it'd be really helpful if there was some permissible equivalent of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `item` variable is of a class (or struct) defined by you, then you could create a method inside like this:

```cs
class People {
  /* ... */
  public bool Enabled() {
    return IsEnabled == "true";
  }
}
```

Then you can do that:

```cs
bool? foo = model.People.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Age > 21 && x.Name.StartsWith("Jo"))?.Enabled();
```

However, I don't really know why you don't want to write it on 2 lines?
In my opinion it is better on 2 lines because it is easier to debug: when you put a break point you can inspect the value of `item`. And I prefer also for code readability if the expression is quite long like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try the following.

```
var foo = model.People
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Age > 21 && x.Name.StartsWith("Jo"))
    ?.IsEnabled == "true";
```

Comment: This is what I tried along the way, but it doesn't actually produce the same result as the snippets in my question. In my example, if `SingleOrDefault` returns null, the value of `foo` will be `null`. In your snippet, if `SingleOrDefault` returns null then the `== "true"` evaluation is essentially saying "if `null == "true"`", and therefore `foo` gets set to false. I made a fiddle to demonstrate: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9YPY5w.